# SDL2 + OpenGL crashes on shaders

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl-2

I'm trying to learn SDL2, modern OpenGL, etc...
Below is the code I've adapted from tutorial for use with SDL2.
I have managed to get everything else to work, but for some reason the **shader part crashes the program.**..

...I'm unable to get any console output to work (any tips on that?).
I'm using Eclipse.

Also if you find any other fixable spots on the code, please feel free to
point them out.

Program compiles without any errors or warnings.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>

const int WINDOW_W = 1280;
const int WINDOW_H = 720;
const int WINDOW_X = 200;
const int WINDOW_Y = 200;


// FUNCTIONS

/* Shader loader:
 * Handles loading GLSL vertex and fragment shaders
 */
GLuint ShaderLoad(const char * vertex_file_path, const char * fragment_file_path)
{
    // Vertex shader ID
    GLuint VertexShaderID = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);

    //Read the vertex shader files
    std::string VertexShaderCode;
    std::ifstream VertexShaderStream(vertex_file_path, std::ios::in);

    if (VertexShaderStream.is_open())
    {
        std::string Line = "";

        while (getline(VertexShaderStream, Line))
        {
            VertexShaderCode += "\n" + Line;
        }

        VertexShaderStream.close();
    }

    GLint Result = GL_FALSE;
    int InfoLogLength;

    // Compile vertex shader
    char const * VertexSourcePointer = VertexShaderCode.c_str();
    glShaderSource(VertexShaderID, 1, &VertexSourcePointer, NULL);
    glCompileShader(VertexShaderID);

    // Check vertex shader
    glGetShaderiv(VertexShaderID, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &Result);
    glGetShaderiv(VertexShaderID, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &InfoLogLength);
    std::vector<char> VertexShaderErrorMessage(InfoLogLength);
    glGetShaderInfoLog(VertexShaderID, InfoLogLength, NULL, &VertexShaderErrorMessage[0]);

    // Fragment shader ID
    GLuint FragmentShaderID = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

    std::string FragmentShaderCode;
    std::ifstream FragmentShaderStream(fragment_file_path, std::ios::in);
    if(FragmentShaderStream.is_open()){
        std::string Line = "";
        while(getline(FragmentShaderStream, Line))
            FragmentShaderCode += "\n" + Line;
        FragmentShaderStream.close();
    }

    // Compile Fragment Shader
    printf("Compiling shader : %s\n", fragment_file_path);
    char const * FragmentSourcePointer = FragmentShaderCode.c_str();
    glShaderSource(FragmentShaderID, 1, &FragmentSourcePointer , NULL);
    glCompileShader(FragmentShaderID);

    // Check Fragment Shader
    glGetShaderiv(FragmentShaderID, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &Result);
    glGetShaderiv(FragmentShaderID, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &InfoLogLength);
    std::vector<char> FragmentShaderErrorMessage(InfoLogLength);
    glGetShaderInfoLog(FragmentShaderID, InfoLogLength, NULL, &FragmentShaderErrorMessage[0]);
    fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", &FragmentShaderErrorMessage[0]);

    // Link the program
    fprintf(stdout, "Linking program\n");
    GLuint ProgramID = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(ProgramID, VertexShaderID);
    glAttachShader(ProgramID, FragmentShaderID);
    glLinkProgram(ProgramID);

    // Check the program
    glGetProgramiv(ProgramID, GL_LINK_STATUS, &Result);
    glGetProgramiv(ProgramID, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &InfoLogLength);
    std::vector<char> ProgramErrorMessage(InfoLogLength);
    glGetProgramInfoLog(ProgramID, InfoLogLength, NULL, &ProgramErrorMessage[0]);
    fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", &ProgramErrorMessage[0]);

    glDeleteShader(VertexShaderID);
    glDeleteShader(FragmentShaderID);

    return ProgramID;
}



//GLuint programID = ShaderLoad("vshader.glsl", "fshader.glsl");



// Main
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    //Variables
    SDL_Window * SDLWindow = NULL;
    SDL_GLContext GLContext;
    SDL_Event event;

    static const GLfloat g_vertex_buffer_data[] = {
       -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
       1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
       0.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
    };

    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);

    SDLWindow = SDL_CreateWindow("ELSA",
                                 WINDOW_X, WINDOW_Y,
                                 WINDOW_W, WINDOW_H,
                                 SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL | SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE);

    GLContext = SDL_GL_CreateContext(SDLWindow);
    SDL_GL_MakeCurrent(SDLWindow, GLContext);

    SDL_GL_SetAttribute( SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute( SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION, 3);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute( SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER, 1);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute( SDL_GL_DEPTH_SIZE, 24);
    SDL_GL_SetSwapInterval(1);

    // OPENGL INIT

    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
    glewInit();

    GLuint vertexbuffer;
    GLuint VertexArrayID;

    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VertexArrayID);
    glBindVertexArray(VertexArrayID);

    // Generate 1 buffer, put the resulting identifier in vertexbuffer
    glGenBuffers(1, &vertexbuffer);

    // The following commands will talk about our 'vertexbuffer' buffer
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexbuffer);

    // Give our vertices to OpenGL.
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,
                 sizeof(g_vertex_buffer_data),
                 g_vertex_buffer_data, GL_STATIC_DRAW);




    while(true)
    {
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&event)) // Get all events per frame
        {
            if (event.type == SDL_QUIT)
            {
                return false;
            }
            if (event.type == SDL_WINDOWEVENT_RESIZED)
            {
                glViewport(0, 0,
                           SDL_GetWindowSurface(SDLWindow)->w,
                           SDL_GetWindowSurface(SDLWindow)->h);
            }
        }

        //OpenGL code
        glClearColor(0.15, 0.15, 0.30, 1.0);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        // Use shader
        //glUseProgram(programID);

        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexbuffer);
        glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*)0);

        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

        SDL_GL_SwapWindow(SDLWindow);
        glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
    }

    SDL_GL_DeleteContext(GLContext);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(SDLWindow);
    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Calling `SDL_GL_SetAttribute()` *after* `SDL_CreateWindow()` is not effective: ["Use this function to set an OpenGL window attribute **before** window creation."](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GL_SetAttribute)

Comment: Your don't call `ShaderLoad()` anywhere.  Or `glUseProgram()`.

Comment: Edit in your shaders.

Comment: In the version of your program that was crashing did you actually call `ShaderLoad()` out in global scope (like the current commented version), before you made a GL context current?